# How can I style a client-side component using 'use client' in an SSR page in NextJS 14?

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css, server-side-rendering, react-slick, next.js14

I have a NextJS 14 application. I am implementing a carousel component using an external npm package. Let's just pick the popular `react-slick` as an example.

After I create a minimal carousel component using `react-slick` my app crashes in dev and I get the error:

> **"Error: Super expression must either be null or a function, not undefined"**

All of the [StackOverflow answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74614922/super-expression-must-either-be-null-or-a-function-nextjs-13) suggest this happens because Next 14 is server-side rendered by default, and the carousel needs to be client-side for interactivity, so I need to use `'use client'` at the top of the file. That works.

However, I would like to override some of the styles that come with the component, and adding them in my `/src/styles/globals.css` file has no effect whatsoever.

I have tried using hyper-specific selectors, and I have tried CSS modules as well. None of these options have any effect on the client-side rendered component styling.

This is likely because styles are created, purged, and minified at build time and the client-side component is only rendered on the client.

Is there any way to style a `'use clients'` component in a NextJS 14 server-side rendered page?

Comment: Will you provide a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? The styles are working fine when I tried to reproduce it in [this example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-slick-simple-slider-with-custom-styles?file=app%2FSlider.tsx).

Comment: You are correct @Rico. The issue arose because I was placing styles for this component nested in the @layer base class of my `src/styles/globals.css` file. Moving the styles into their own section fixed the issue completely.